# How to follow or like other using Intagram API in PHP

Tags: php, instagram-api

I am looking for Instagram API calls that will allow me to 'follow' and 'like' using PHP. I am using [this code](https://www.codexworld.com/login-with-instagram-using-php/) to login with an account in PHP.

After login I want to send follow and like requests but I don't know how? I am new to the Instagram API and apologies if my question has already been asked.

Comment: have you check the permission ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307719/instagramm-api-php-follow-user